# Simple HTML DOM - (direct) child selector

Tags: php, css-selectors, simple-html-dom

How can i get the inner text of the `a` element with text *Title*?

I'm trying with `$html->find('#someid p > a')` but it includes all nested descendant `a` elements.

```
<div id="someid">
    <tr>... Same structure ...<tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                <a href="#">Title</a>
                <br>
                <span class="someClass">
                    <a href="#">text1</a>
                    <a href="#">text2</a>
                    <a href="#">text3</a>
                    <a href="#">text4</a>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>text5</p>
        </td>
        <td>text6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>...<tr>
</div>
```

Comment: By what criterion do you want to select it - it being the first `a`, or containing `Text`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try:

```
$e = $html->find(''#someid p > a', 0);
//or type first_child
```

Comment: It seems OK, only first a is returned but how can I get the innertext ?

Comment: This works in my case $e = $html->find('#someid p > a', 0)->innertext;

Comment: Just to make this clear to others: The child selector seems to not work in Simple HTML DOM. The reason this solution works is that it simply picks the first out of the five matches. Would the desired target be placed after `span.someClass` it wouldn't work and would just return the first `<a>` inside `span.someClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `filter(':first')` or `filter(':first-child')`? You may also try using the `->firstChild` lookup.

I assume you need the first descendent. Otherwise, you could consider using an id for the specific anchor tag.

Comment: Yeah. Just noticed that. I'm relatively new to this too. How about `firstChild`? Does that work for you?